# Is possible/safe to use PHP Threads at Laravel Artisan Commands?

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel

I have some artisan commands running at my application regularly at a certain time.

Now suppose I have multiple matrices multiplications, which I can easily parallelize using [PHP threads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php).

The question is: Is it possible at Laravel context? And *should* I do this or take another option?